# Why while() creates magic?

Tags: java, while-loop

I was writing a program to find armstrong numbers from 100 to 999. If I give number as an input program works but if I check number using while loop it says that every number not an armstrong number. I can't understand why.

That is the code:

```
 package armstrong;

 //import java.util.Scanner;

 public class Armstrong {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int n, sum = 0, temp, remainder, digits = 0;

        //Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        //System.out.println("Input a number to check if it is an Armstrong number");      
        //n = in.nextInt();
        n = 100;
        while (n <= 999) {
            temp = n;

            // Count number of digits

            while (temp != 0) {
                digits++;
                temp = temp / 10;
            }

            temp = n;

            while (temp != 0) {
                remainder = temp % 10;
                sum = sum + power(remainder, digits);
                temp = temp / 10;
            }

            if (n != sum) System.out.println(n + " is not an Armstrong number.");
            else System.out.println("Armstrong number:" + n);

            n++;

        }
    }

    static int power(int n, int r) {
        int c, p = 1;

        for (c = 1; c <= r; c++)
        p = p * n;

        return p;
    }
 }
```

Comment: Please next time pay attention to formatting your code correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should initialize digits, sum to zero in your loop like:

```
while (n <= 999) {
    digits = 0;
    sum = 0
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on this page: http://www.cs.mtu.edu/~shene/COURSES/cs201/NOTES/chap04/arms.html

You should set `sum` to back to zero inside the loop:

```
    while(n <= 999) {
  temp = n;
  sum = 0;
  ...
}
```

and `power` method should be:

```
static int power(int n) {
  return n * n * n;
 }
```

Hope it helps.